# Question about Taylor series expansion in complex numbers involving branch cut

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, power-series

I want to consider a Taylor series expansion over complex numbers of $(i + z)^{-1/2}$ around $0$.
Using the usual formula I get
$$
(i + z)^{-1/2} = i^{-1/2} - \frac{1}{2} i^{-3/2} z + .... 
$$
I can see that the series converge around $|z| < 1$.

When I was computing this, I just used the formula. But then I realized $i^{-m/2}$ is apriori not well defined since there are more than one choice for this... so the above formula doesn't make sense as it is. How can I fix this issue? Choosing arbitrary choice of $i^{-m/2}$ for each $m$ doesn't sound a good idea.

Comment: There is a branch point at $-i$.  You need to choose a branch cut.  Let's suppose we choose the cut to be the straight line path from $-i$ along the negative imaginary axis.  Choose the branch on which $\log(i)=i\pi/2$.  Then for $|z|<1$ $(z+i)^{-1/2}$ is analytic and you can proceed as you did.

Comment: Do I have to choose a branch cut for $(i + z)^{-1/2}$ for each $z$ first? or perhaps choosing a branch for $i$ determines the branch for $(i + z)^{-1/2}$ for all $z$?

Comment: Hi @johnnyT.  Yes, we choose a branch cut and a branch on which we define $(z+i)^{-1/2}$.  See my posted solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\log(z+i)$ has a branch point at $z=-i$ and is multivalued on the plane.  We can cut the plane and choose a branch such that on chosen branch of the cut plane, $\log(z+i)$ is defined and analytic.

---

We shall cut the plane from the branch point at $-i$ along the negative imaginary axis to the point at infinity on the sphere.  And we will define $\log(z+i)$ such that $-\pi<\arg(z+i)\le\pi$.

---

Now, let $f(z)=(z+i)^{-1/2}\equiv e^{-\frac12\log(z+i)}$.

Note that on the chosen branch, $\arg(i)=\pi/2$ and we have $f(0)=e^{-\frac12 \log(i)}=e^{-i\pi/4}$.

Furthermore, $f$ is analytic on the cut plane with its Taylor series around $0$ and for $|z|<1$ given by

$$f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)z^n}{n!}$$

Looking at the first few terms, we have

$$\begin{align}
f(0)&=e^{-i\pi/4}\\\\
f'(0)&=-\frac12 e^{-i3\pi/4}\\\\
f''(0)&=\frac34 e^{-i5\pi/4}
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: by "cut plane" it means the complex plane with $\mathbb{R}_{\leq0}$ removed?

Comment: perhaps $i \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, not $\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$

Comment: The branch cut is a ray from $-i$ to $-i \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

I would write

$$\begin{aligned}
(i + z)^{-1/2} &= \left(i(1 - iz)\right)^{-1/2}\\
&= e^{-i \frac{\pi}{4}}(1 - iz)^{-1/2}\\
&= e^{-i \frac{\pi}{4}}(1 + \frac{i}{2} z + \dots)
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: given any $z$, does one have to choose a branch to define $(1 - iz)^{-1/2}$ first? and how would this reflect in the expression for the series?

Comment: In what I wrote, the branch chosen is the one for which $1^{-1/2} = 1$, vs. $1^{-1/2} = -1$ for the other branch.